# C# - Stream.Read reading null bytes

Tags: c#, networking, stream

On receiving Multipart data from the browser (which has a size of greater than ~2KB), I start receiving null '\0' bytes after the first few chunks which are relevant when I use:

```
_Stream.Read(ByteArray, Offset, ContentLength);
```

But, if I divide the ContentLength into small buffers (around 2KB each) **AND** add a delay of 1ms after each call to Read(), then it works fine:

```
for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
    _Stream.Read(ByteArray, Offset * i, BufferSize);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
}
```

But, adding delay is quite slow. How to prevent reading null bytes. How can I know how many bytes have been written by the browser.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `0x00` bytes were not actually received, they were never written to.

`Stream.Read()` returns the number of bytes actually read, which is in your case often less than `BufferSize`. Small amounts of data typically arrive in a single message, in which case the problem does not occur.

The delay might "work" in your test scenario because by then the network layer has buffered more than `BufferSize` data. It will probably fail in a production environment.

So you'll need to change your code into something like:

```
int remaining = ContentLength;
int offset = 0;  
while (remaining > 0)
{
    int bytes = _Stream.Read(ByteArray, offset, remaining);
    if (bytes == 0)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("Server disconnected before the expected amount of data was received");
    }

    offset += bytes;
    remaining -= bytes;
}
```